# Lambert-Beer's law coefficient

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

While the Beer's law equation is $A=a \cdot b \cdot c$, according to my book, $a$ is a coefficient which is:

> a characteristic property of the analyte in a specific solvent, and its values will depend on the wavelength of absorption radiation.

This is quite unclear to me.

If we have for example  $a= 1.5$, what does that exactly tell us ? *What* do we know when this coefficient is given ? Or is this just a constant that helps us to solve the equation?

Comment: A large value for $a$ indicates a strong interaction between light and the chromophore.  In other words, the larger $a$ the stronger the absorption of light by the chromophore.

Comment: Think of a shooting gallery at a carnival, where you fire pellets (‘photons of light’) at targets (‘molecules’) randomly moving around in a deep shooting gallery. Then b is how deep the gallery is, c is how many targets there are in the ‘volume’ of the gallery (that the moving targets move around in) and **a is the size of the target, i.e., its cross-sectional area.** Only a small fraction of fired pellets will be transmitted entirely through the shooting gallery if there are many large targets and the depth is large. Conversely, a large fraction of fired pellets will be transmitted entirely

Comment: through the shooting gallery if the targets are small, there are not many of them in the gallery and the gallery is short. In other words, a, c, and b, respectively, are small. The transmittance is the number of transmitted pellets divided by the total fired pellets. Then A, the absorbance, is defined as the negative logarithm, base 10, of the transmittance.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, I recommend to reformulate Beer-Lambert's law in a way more frequently met in (analytical) chemistry, i.e.

$\mbox{ABS} = c \cdot{} l \cdot{} \varepsilon = \log_{10} \frac{I_0}{I}$

because then it more obvious that the (dimensionless) absorption (ABS) recorded is the product of analyte concentration ($c$), optical path length ($l$) across the sample investigated, and the molecular extinction coefficient ($\varepsilon{}$).  Absorption equally is defined as the logarithm (to base of ten) of the fraction of incoming light intensity ($I_0$) and light intensity that is transmitted across the sample ($I$).

Now to your question.  While concentration $c$ and optical path length $l$ may be changed (the later, for example, by exchanging a measurement cell of 1 cm path length to one of 2 mm or 5 cm -- depending on the setup of the spectrometer), the molecular extinction coefficient $\varepsilon$ is indeed more valuable than just assistance to solve the equation.  It relates to the ease the analyte may absorb irradiation.

UV-Vis spectroscopy investigates electronic transitions, prominently of $\pi{}$-systems (like of alkene double, and aromatic bonds), yet investigation of electronic transitions of $n$- (non-bonded, like of carbonyl-O electrons), $d$- (for example in transition metal complexes) and $\sigma{}$-electrons (in the short wavelength UV-range).  In principle, these transitions are discrete, i.e. only photons of this attuned energy ($h\nu{}$) that fits the energy gap between the electronic ground state and the excited state are absorbed.

An analyte molecule may possess more than one allowed electronic transitions.  They may occur simultaneously, with different efficiency.  For example, many organic dyes have a strong absorption in the visible range, like indigo has one around 600 nm.  Yet if you tune the wavelength of investigation to short wavelengths, below 250 nm, for example, absorption may still occur, too, yet to a lesser extent.  (This eventually contributes to processes that indigo stained cloths fade over time, for example.)

---

Side note:  The molecular extinction coefficient $\varepsilon$ depends on other, additional parameters than the "solvent" and "wavelength of investigation".  Varying the pH-value, ionic strength of the solution, presence/absence of other dissolved molecules than of your analyte and solvent may alter $\varepsilon{}$, too.  Do not forget, the concentration $c$ of your analyte may influence $\varepsilon{}$, too -- pointing to (concentration dependent)  potential dimerisation / aggregation of your analyte (for example [charge transfer complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-transfer_complex)).

Comment: Thanks but i find this a little bit off topic ( not helpful ), I asked only for the coefficient meaning and not for the transitions that may occur. Yet the only thing that seemed to be related is ' it relates to the ease the analyte may absorb irradiation ', which is also hard to understand (not explained well ).

Comment: The absorption observed is result of changes of the quantum state. There are selection rules, according to them some transitions are "allowed" (more probable), and others "forbidden (less probable to occur).  Wavefunction, symmetry, and kind of experiment come into play here.  This is an other avenue to answer to your question.